# Node.js + Git: How To Avoid Adding Module Dependencies to Repository

Tags: git, node.js, github, repository, npm

### My Situation

I'm developing a Node.js application as `npm` module.

In order to be able to run this app, I installed all the `npm` dependencies. So, my project contains some `./node_module/` folders containing external module dependency builds.

I maintain my project using `git` and I publish using a GitHub repository.

### My Problem

I don't want to publish all my local builds of the `npm` module dependencies on GitHub.

I only want to publish my own code. The users of my module should use `npm install` to get the current builds dependencies.

### My Question

What's the best way to **keep the dependency builts away from my GitHub repository**?

Thanks for your answer (or comment). - If anything's unclear, please comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the root directory of your project (the one above `node_modules`) add the following line to the end of your .gitignore file (create it if needed):

```
node_modules
```

That will prevent the node_modules files from being added to the GitHub repository.

Then create or open the package.json file in that same directory, and add a `dependencies` section like so:

```
{
   "dependencies": {
      "module": "0.0.x",
      ...
   }
}
```

Generally, you'll want to use 0.0.x for the format of your versions. This ensures you get bug fixes but no breaking or major changes in your dependencies, so they will stay compatible with your module.

The package.json will tell npm to install anything listed in `dependencies` whenever your module gets installed. You can [read more about package.json here](http://blog.nodejitsu.com/package-json-cheat-sheet).

And here is [a great little overview](http://anders.janmyr.com/2012/04/writing-node-module.html) of the entire process.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the modules from being added to your git repository (and therefore to github) you can add the node_modules folder to your .gitignore file. (As @Kato just pointed out)

However, you might consider keeping the modules in your repository to make sure everybody has the exact same version. Using npm install could lead to people getting different (more recent) version of a module.

This is a good blog post on the subject: http://www.futurealoof.com/posts/nodemodules-in-git.html

Comment: Dependencies should not be part of the versioned files. package.json is there to specify a particular version of a dependency if needed.

Comment: How does checking in node_modules work when you have binary modules that need to be compiled? Often times people develop in different environments than where the code is deployed